# how to read files from zip folder placed in server using .net

Tags: .net, windows, zip

I have a zip file in my server. I am not suppose to download that zip file to extract its contents.

Eg., "test.zip" contains folder "test" with files "test1.jpg" & "test2.jpg".

I should not download "test.zip" folder but I should find files inside test folder placed inside that "test.zip".

If files available then I should download that jpg files and place it in my application path.

If this question is clear please help me to get out from this problem. I tried in net but I nothing to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

then to get file from it try

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
 {
     ZipEntry e = zip["YourFileName"];
     e.Extract(OutputStream);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question. Why don't you want to download the zip file? If you don't want to download the zip file don't store the images in a zip file, just store the images in a folder called "test" on your server.

As far as I'm aware you can't download files separately from a zip file.